# How to make ticks fill the band width in Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to use tick marks to separate a stacked bar but I can't figure out how to make the tick marks full width of the responsive bar mark ([example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGUYbAO4QABPThn1cQUh1yIMLWaZxMxuHFlmj6iHA4JnDqZkiyyhbwZrIMCEykoWwAZmZQAJ7CESHmDBA0smQWNFAA1mbI6qUQlIogxjTK9GggUHKYSAUhdcr2KKigxEiCDGpoANqgABJs-oHB6mgAjGIADEoAwpkFqv5oAEwAvgrTswFBnouoS6vrIFtZuxAHx6dzF92o+7eb29l7qAAzK8QDN3gtlmtfo8cmhgSdQWd5pdlj97n8nnDDgBdY4gOzpT6TECVUpoUCYdI4OAtJhIRZ47xtZQFMjkkDpdnJGi2ZQtMHnCFKSnUloARwY4R0HR0pBAeIAHlyeYI+egHjtYcKqTT0LMWbJhvLDiDSeyRbqQDoynU2oJZi0bHzGbJmaz2ZyBiBubz+UiPottaL0BKpXR7DQ5UoIB0bahMOpRorlb71RitVadS19QUjSacYcgA)).

[image: stacked bar with ticks]

The reason I am doing this is I want the ticks to look like separators between the stacked bars. Another approach I have tried is setting stroke ([example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGUYbAO4QABPThn1cQUh1yIMLWaZxMxuHFlmj6iHA4JnDqZkiyyhbwZrIMCEykoWwAZmZQAJ7CESHmDBA0smQWNFAA1mbI6qUQlIogxjTK9GggUHKYSAUhdcr2KKigxEiCDGpoANqgABJs-oHB6mgAjGIADEoAwpkFqv5oAEwAvgrTswFBnouoS6vrIFtZuxAHx6dzF92o+7eb29l7qAAzK8QDN3gtlmtfo8cmhgSdQWd5pdlj97n8nnDDgBdY4gOzpT6TECVUpoUCYdI4OAtJhIRZ47xtZQFMjkkDpdnJGi2ZQtMHnCFKSnUloARwY4R0HR0pBAeIAHlyeYI+egHjtYcKqTT0LMWbJhvKlBBMOo2KVdYNhqMWpg2Mh7fLDjjDkA)) on the bar mark but this adds a border to the left and right of the bars which I don't want. I only want the separator to be between two bars vertically.

[image: stacked bar with stroke]

Comment: By full width, do you mean you want to match the width of `bar` mark ?

Comment: Yes exactly. To match the width of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `width` config inside your `mark` objects.

Refer the below config or [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGUYbAO4QABPThn1cQUh1yIMLWaZxMxuHFlmj6iHA4JnDqZkiyyhbwZrIMCEykoWwAZmZQAJ7CESHmDBA0smQWNFAA1mbI6qUQlIogxjTK9GggUHKYSAUhdcr2KKigDOqCLb0dBFBI-lIy8gC+Snbp3agA2qCVpWigmOk4cC1MU3UNTTBoYgAMCyDebcoFZNsg6c-JNLbKLQASbP6BwXUdV2+xaAEcGOEdB0dKQQDcAB5vD6CL7oADCmQKqn8wL2B3QfwesiQIzm5IUGymWwGIBBBLpJS2Sjagj+LUwbGQnJOjWaqCuNzubGJT1pr1p70+Pz+ASCniBSnp4Mhsmh9hocKUEA6ZTQmHUDDgiOR0oxWOyuKV+JaRIKpPh5IAunMgA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Shows the relationship between horsepower and the numbver of cylinders using tick marks.",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": 50},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "color": "tomato", "width": 50},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
        "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The chart is responsive and I would like to keep it that way rather than setting absolute values. Is there a way to set the tick width to the width of the band rather than a static value?

Comment: The tick is not respecting the containers responsive behaviour whenever I try to shrink the chart. The bar chart's width gets reduced but the ticks width is not reduced (without `width` config). Can you tell me why are you using the `ticks` mark ? as it seem to be look like a bar chart so you can just use the orange mark as a bar chart ?

Comment: I've updated the original question with more details.